# p4 changes command works only for files how can i get latest synced cl for directories

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

commands like p4 changes work only for files how can I get latest synced cl for a directory. when I use these command s for directories I get this.

commands I tried
p4 changes -m1 "path#have"
p4 changes -m1 "path"#have
p4 changes -m1 "path"

I did add '...' with the path

result latest cl on perforce server

I expect last synced cl of directory

These commands are giving me desired result for files but not for directories.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
p4 changes -m1 path/...#have
```

Note that to join the file specifier (which needs the `...` to match files in a directory path) and revision specifier they need to be part of the *same argument* -- if there's a space between them on the command line they'll be interpreted as two different arguments (so you'll get the union of changes for the path at `#head` and the revision specifier `#have` across all paths).

If `path` contains spaces, quotes (which keep the shell from splitting the path into multiple arguments before passing it to `p4`) go around the entire argument:

```
p4 changes -m1 "path with spaces/...#have"
```